# Facebook Graph Api : Searching name in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, python-requests

Hello how i can possible to search name on facebook graph api like "John Doe" instead of username or userid? I'm using requests module of python thanks

Comment: You can't; Facebook does not provide an API to search for users any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately facebook-graph API doesn't have endpoints for searching users but you can simply use the fb package for logging-in and automate your search using the module [facebook-scraper](https://github.com/kevinzg/facebook-scraper) package

**search fb username**

you can get the `cookies.txt` using [cookie extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/getcookiestxt/bgaddhkoddajcdgocldbbfleckgcbcid?hl=en) that extracts local cookie file into text.

```
from facebook_scraper import get_profile
get_profile("zuck") # Or get_profile("zuck", cookies="cookies.txt")
```

```
{'About': "I'm trying to make the world a more open place.",
 'Education': 'Harvard University\n'
              'Computer Science and Psychology\n'
              '30 August 2002 - 30 April 2004\n'
              'Phillips Exeter Academy\n'
              'Classics\n'
              'School year 2002\n'
              'Ardsley High School\n'
              'High School\n'
              'September 1998 - June 2000',
 'Favourite Quotes': '"Fortune favors the bold."\n'
                     '- Virgil, Aeneid X.284\n'
                     '\n'
                     '"All children are artists. The problem is how to remain '
                     'an artist once you grow up."\n'
                     '- Pablo Picasso\n'
                     '\n'
                     '"Make things as simple as possible but no simpler."\n'
                     '- Albert Einstein',
 'Name': 'Mark Zuckerberg',
 'Places lived': [{'link': '/profile.php?id=104022926303756&refid=17',
                   'text': 'Palo Alto, California',
                   'type': 'Current town/city'},
                  {'link': '/profile.php?id=105506396148790&refid=17',
                   'text': 'Dobbs Ferry, New York',
                   'type': 'Home town'}],
 'Work': 'Chan Zuckerberg Initiative\n'
         '1 December 2015 - Present\n'
         'Facebook\n'
         'Founder and CEO\n'
         '4 February 2004 - Present\n'
         'Palo Alto, California\n'
         'Bringing the world closer together.'}
```

credits to : facebook-scraper documentation